# How to hide Google Storage bucket path and image name from URL

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm using Google Storage to store profile pictures of my users. I have couple of thousands pictures.

Now the pictures are being saved in a bucket like so:
data/images/profiles/USER_ID.jpg

So the URL to an image:
https://storage.cloud.google.com/data/images/profiles/USER_ID.jpg

I don't want users being able to see someone else picture by just knowing their USER_ID, and still, It has to be the USER_ID for easier search from a developer's side.

I can't use Signed URL as my users do not have a google account, and the pictures from the storage are fetched from a Mobile Application.

Is there a way to keep the file names as they are in the storage, but simple hide the path+filename from the URL?

```
https://storage.cloud.google.com/fc720d5c05411b03e5e2a6692f8d7d61.jpg -> points to https://storage.cloud.google.com/data/images/profiles/USER_ID.jpg
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You have several options. Here are a few:

- Have users request the URL for another user from the server, then have the server decide whether or not the user is allowed to see the image. If so, have the server (which does have a service account) generate a signed URL and pass it back to the user (or redirect to it). This way, although the user may know the user ID of another user and the URL of their image, they still can't see the image unless the server agrees that this is okay.
- Use Firebase Storage to manage the images, which will still store them in GCS but will give you Firebase's auth support.
- Proxy the images through your app, either an app engine app or something running in GCE or GKE. This lets you hide everything about the source of the image, including the user ID, but has the downside of requiring all of the data to pass through your service.
- Reexamine your requirements. "Easier search on the developer's side" may not be as important as you think, and you need to way the benefit of that vs the cost of working around it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Google Images API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/images/) available on AppEngine. You can link your Cloud Storage objects with Google Images API and use benefits of this API - secure URLs, transform and resize images using URL parameters.
You only need to prepare [servingURL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/ImagesService#getServingUrl-com.google.appengine.api.images.ServingUrlOptions-) for every image stored in GCS and persist this serving URL (for example in Google Datastore)

```
ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
ServingUrlOptions suo = ServingUrlOptions.Builder
    .withGoogleStorageFileName(gcsImageObjectPath)
    .secureUrl(true);
String servingUrl = imagesService.getServingUrl(suo);
```